# What type of connector is this? Looks like two pins but is only one

Tags: connector, identification, wiring

Aside from looking like an upside-down Wall-E, what is this connector called?  It may look like there are two pins, but they are the same contact.[image]

Comment: Looks to be something that is called a "Faston" connector.  That's probably somebody's trademarked name but is the name that is used in both the Electrical and Electronics industries.

Comment: It doesn't look like a Faston(tm) connector to me.  A couple of better pictures, from different angles, and a picture of the mating part, might help someone identify it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is in the background in this picture?

Comment: A picture that actually has the thing you want to identify in focus WOULD be helpful. Many pixels, lot's of zoom, but blurry as heck says - yep, thats a blurry red thing on the end of a wire.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry for the blurry photo.  My camera was too shakey and was annoying.  And the device in the background is a mat that produces a short circuit output when someone steps on it.  I'm trying to connect it to my arduino.

Comment: Unless it is something standard (blade terminal) I would snip it off and add standard connector unless you have to reterminate LOTS AND have an expectation of replacement floor switches being supplied with the eact same connector in future that you want to be able to replace without changing connectors to a more standard one.

Answer (score 1):

These are called *Quick disconnect terminals*.  It's a very generic family of connectors.

[image] ([page where the picture came from](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?channel=products&chanName=family&key=quick_disconnect))

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a blade terminal, although I could only speculate on the size.

Here's a picture of what the other side looks like:
[image: blade terminals]

edit: It could also be a spade terminal (which looks like this):
[image]